# How to kill javaw.exe

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am learning Spring MVC using Maven project and I facing a problem. This is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello Spring MVC");
        return "helloworld";
    }
}
```

I run my project by this way (I am using Eclip Neon):
Right click on project > Run as > Run configurations > Right click on Maven Build > New > Enter name, base directory and goals > Apply > Run. Done.

When I access this url

> http://localhost:8080/DemoSpringMVC/hello

the `"helloworld"` page will be displayed, this is simple.

Now I want to change `@RequestMapping("/hello")` to `@RequestMapping("/hello1")`, like this

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello1")
    public String hello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello Spring MVC");
        return "helloworld";
    }
}
```

I run my project again, access this url and I got error "`The requested resource is not available."`

> http://localhost:8080/DemoSpringMVC/hello1

I try to access this and `"helloworld"` still be displayed

> http://localhost:8080/DemoSpringMVC/hello

I open Task manager and I figure out that the `"javaw.exe"` create a new instance every time I run my project, but the older version is always get affect.
I try to kill all `"javaw.exe"` processes by hand, run the project again and it works.

So the question is, how to kill old `"javaw.exe"` process everytime I run my project??? Or maybe I build or run Maven project wrong way?

**RESOLVED:** I realize I can run a maven project follow the normal way (By tomcat), then the problem resolved. Thank you all.

Comment: There should be a server window somewhere showing you the logs from your server. There's probably a 'stop' button on or near it. This should be pressed before you run your server to kill off the old process before starting a new one.

Comment: @Kai do you use Spring Boot or Spring? How do you exactly start your server?

Comment: @EngineerDollery Yeah I know, but I'm newbie so I dont know where is that button and I don't even know that button exist or not.

Comment: @nazar_art I'm newbie then I don't know what exactly what I am using but I think it is Spring because I dont know what is Boot Spring.
I start server by this way: 
Right click on project > Run as > Run configurations > Right click on Maven Build > New > Enter name, base directory and goals> Apply > Run.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running a second time, you probably want to redeploy your running code.  See https://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/

Comment: Thank you but this solved the problem with tomcat server, not maven project. I have try to find the same way like this but got nothing.